# Domain of function in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Why is it that when we consider functions over $R^n$ such that the limit as $|x|→∞$is the same in any direction then we can identify their domain with $S^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{S}^n$. The idea is that you're adjoining the point $\infty$ at infinity to the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$, and since any way we go to infinity yields the same value $L$, we can assign $f(\infty)=L$.

A very visual way to see this is using stereographic projection:

[image]

In the image above, we create a bijection between $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows. For any point $z$ on the sphere except for the north pole $N$, consider the ray $Nz$ emanating from $N$ and through $z$. This ray crosses the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ at exactly one point $Z$. The association $z\longleftrightarrow Z$ is a homeomorphism $h$ between $\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{N\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Observe that as $z$ approaches the north pole $N$, $Z$ 'approaches' infinity, that is, becomes unbounded in norm. We can then extend the homeomorphism to all of $\mathbb{S}^2$ by assigning $h(N)=\infty$. This creates an hommeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$.

Stereographic projection is used, for instance, in the Riemman sphere model for the complex plane.

Comment: Could you give an example o real line and a circle, it is more easy to see

Comment: It's exactly the same. Something like [this image](http://xahlee.info/complex/1/sphere_proj.png).

Comment: i am not undersanding why if we have $f(\infty)=L$ means to add a point to $R^n$

Comment: Because $\infty\notin\mathbb{R}^n$. We are adding the point $\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is generally also known as the *extended* real space.

Comment: how is that imposing $f(\infty)=L $ make $ \infty\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: No, $\infty$ does NOT belong to $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ exists and equals $L$, then we may define a continuous extension $F$ of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$ by setting $F(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(\infty)=L$. Then, we notice that $\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^n$, via the stereographic projection, so that we may 'think' of $F$ as a continuous extension of $f$ defined on $\mathbb{S}^n$.